# Arabic Language in AIX and Java Program

Tags: java, character-encoding, console, aix

I have a JAVA application which reads a message from a T24 banking system, one of these parameters is in Arabic language, if I print this parameter on the AIX console it appears as a garbage letters.

I have create a local String and I assigned an Arabic name to that string variable, and I print it on the console, and it appears fine.

I need to print the arabic parameter which I have received from the T24 banking system in the same way that I get it when I use the local arabic string.

What is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: Maybe you could share the code that reads from the "T24 banking system" with us. Probably this system uses a specific character encoding supporting Arabic characters, but your Java code doesn't tell the methods that get the strings from the interface to use this encoding. Then T24 has bytes encoded in encoding A, Java's default is encoding B, so the bytes get misunderstood to represent different characters. In the second case, you are using Java's native characters without the need for any conversion, so that works without any problems.

Comment: You need to find out what encoding the T24 system is providing data in, then read that data in the correct encoding. Show the (relevant) code you use to read the data.

Comment: @OP: you should do some debugging; that should involve checking program-output with a hexviewer (eg od -tx1); checking your localization settings; consulting codetables/charactermaps ( http://www.unicode.org/charts/ )

Comment: Thanks for all of you for this valuable suggestions